# Has research into the aerodynamic properties of non-smooth surfaces suggested any promising directions for future aircraft design?

Tags: aerodynamics

As you might gather from [Can planes benefit from Mitsubishi's Air Lubrication System?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29189) I'm interested in what possibilities there are for radically different approaches to aircraft body surfaces.

Aircraft body surfaces appear to be as smooth as possible, but not all things that fly well are smooth:

- golf balls are dimpled (see the very interesting discussion of [Is a golf ball surface a good idea for wings or fuselage?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24752))
- birds are feathered
- sharks have [placoid scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_scale#Placoid_scales) (yes, I am aware that sharks don't *actually* fly through the air...)

Has scientific or industry research indicated useful possibilities in new surfaces for aircraft body skins - or maybe alternatives to skins altogether?

Comment: You can find a lot of what you want [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=vortex+generator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a golf ball surface a good idea for wings or fuselage?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24752/is-a-golf-ball-surface-a-good-idea-for-wings-or-fuselage)

Comment: @SMSvonderTann: This link is explicitly mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann That's listed as a possibility, but not as the only one.  This questions covers more ground than that one.

Comment: I think boundary layer suction might form the basis of a good answer - several experiments have been done in the past. (Leaving this as a comment as I can't find the references.)

Answer (score 5):

Non-smooth surfaces are already used, particularly in some Military Aircraft. If you've ever run your hand down the fuselage of an FA-18 Hornet you will find the surface is quite rough, much like the skin of a shark. At lower speeds very little is achieved, however at higher speeds small bubbles of air buildup in the indentations of the skin thereby creating an extremely slippery surface.

[Take a look](https://physics.aps.org/story/v17/st6)

[Take a look here too](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/aircraft-paint-suppliers-explore-sharkskin-coating-381646/)

I'm certain my terminology is not correct, sorry about that. I would have put this all into comment, but I'm not allowed yet.

Comment: would you happen to have some references to back up your claims?

Comment: Sadly I don't know what the technology is called. However, a few years back I was lucky enough to get on-board an F18 and commented on the roughness of the skin. The squadron leader told me it was similar to shark skin and developed, at speed, extremely good aerodynamics as a result.

Comment: I did find this: https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/aircraft-paint-suppliers-explore-sharkskin-coating-381646/

Comment: thank you. if you manage to find also other sources, you can edit your answer to add them and make a better answer.

Comment: And this https://physics.aps.org/story/v17/st6

Comment: This is exactly the kind of information I was after, would love to see it written up into a full answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm sure other aircraft have this but my only experience has been with the Hornet 20 years ago, there must be more since then.