# What typical improvements in lift/drag are gained using dimple & zig-zag strips?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, propeller, drag

A golf ball goes twice as far using a dimpled surface. Many European aircraft (especially gliders) use dimple strips or zig-zag tape on propellers, wings, struts etc. Very few US aircraft use these products.

The dimples/holes/perforations are sometimes mechanically stamped onto a part, but more often a metallic or fiber tape is applied to a thick part of the surface. This is using existing after market technology and has nothing to do with "blow holes".

This question *is not how it work*s it is ***HOW WELL it works***!

### What typical improvements in lift/drag are gained and are there any drawbacks to their use?

[image: Dimpled golf ball increase range by twice]

Dimples on golf ball reduces drag and doubles its range.

[image]
[image]

Dimple perforations or strips and zig-zag tape decrease drag on some aircraft surfaces.

Comment: Related: [Has research into the aerodynamic properties of non-smooth surfaces suggested any promising directions for future aircraft design?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29190/3201) and for dimples: [Is a golf ball surface a good idea for wings or fuselage?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24752/3201)

Comment: This question relates to existing technology using ***strips*** - not hypothetical complete surfaces.

Comment: Not suggesting anything, and on the second question, there is an answer which mentions [turbulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulator), and indicates the turbulence pattern needs not be on the whole surface as soon as we know the direction of the airflow.

Comment: I don't think strips/dimples are particularly effective for increasing lift . They reduce drag by transforming the laminar flow over a surface to a turbulent flow so that the flow remains energised and follows the shape of the object instead of separating.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with blow holes. This question is specific to after market dimples and zig-zag tape. It is not how it works it is ***HOW WELL it works!***

Comment: I was told, many years ago, that hail damage was the cheapest damage one could get on their aircraft.  The theory being, insurance pays but no work is done on the dimpled surfaces because there was less drag with the dimples.  True or not, I can't say.