# Which tail type is better in order to obtain higher speed?

Tags: aircraft-design, drag, tail

If I want to design an aircraft that can fly with high speed while loaded, which tail type should I choose.

The mission is to design an aircraft that can move a certain distance with high speed while carrying certain load.

Comment: What does "high speed" mean? Supersonic? Transonic? Hypersonic? 200kts?

Comment: Every single aircraft can transfer some load some distance at some speed. Presumably.

Answer (score 2):

### Lose the tail.

[image]
By Staff Sgt. Bennie J. Davis III [Public domain], [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AB-2_Spirit_original.jpg)

1. Split brake-rudders will do the trick.
2. You can also try and beat NASA and Boeing to the [Active Flow Control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/29192/14897) tails.
3. Or just settle for a [T-tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-tail).

> The horizontal tail plate effectively increases the aspect ratio of the fin by virtue of the 'end plate' effect. The T-tail configuration is especially popular on gliders.

[image]
([*Flight* 1977—PDF](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1977/1977%20-%201899.PDF)) Early Boeing 757/767 designs featured T-tails to reduce drag.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I was hesitated about T-tail and conventional tail ,I'll choose T-tail then